# How can I hide the output of a shell application in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

How can I hide the screen output (printf) of a shell application in Linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292847/how-to-silence-output-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can redirect the output of any program so that it won't be seen.

```
$ program > /dev/null
```

This will redirect the standard output - you'll still see any errors

```
$ program &> /dev/null
```

This will redirect all output, including errors.

Comment: The first one didn't work for wget

Comment: That's cause wget uses stderr for some of it's output. The second one should work.

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to save that wget output to a log file, so when/if your download stops working, you can figure out why. If it's in a script anyway. If this is a one-off type run, then yea, to the trash

Comment: For `wget` you can use the `-q` options to make it quiet.

Comment: Any way to suppress output written directly to /dev/tty?

Comment: +1.  First time seeing &> option. I always used "> /dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: &> seems to work with bash but not with sh. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 36):

There are three I/O devices available on the command line.

```
 standard input  - 0
 standard output - 1
 standard error  - 2
```

To redirect standard output (the default output) to a file (and overwrite the file), use

```
 command > file.log
```

To append to file.log, use two `>`s

```
 command >> file.log
```

To redirect standard error to the file.log, use

```
 command 2> file.log
```

And to append

```
 command 2>> file.log
```

To combine the outputs into one stream and send them all to one place

```
 command > file.log 2>&1
```

This sends 2 (standard error) into 1 (standard output), and sends standard output to file.log

Notice that it's also possible to redirect standard input into a command that expects standard input

```
 command << file.txt
```

For more details, check out the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: Can somebody explain how the `command > file.log 2>&1` works?

Comment: How low of a level would you like to know?

Comment: @nomoreink: it's actually 2 commands, one is `> file` and the second one is `2>&1`. The first one redirects the standard out to a file. The second one takes 2nd file descriptor and redirects it to first one. You can do the reverse, redirect standard output to standard error using `>&2` and then redirect standard error to a file with `2> file`.

Answer (score 16):

Hide standard output:

```
./command >/dev/null
```

Hide standard and error outputs:

```
./command >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Hide standard output and error outputs and release the terminal (run the command in the background):

```
./command >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to hide the output (and not save it to a file), you can use:

Edited:

$ command &> /dev/null

Comment: This will redirect the output to a file called null

Comment: It generated a null file

Comment: you wouldn't have meant /dev/null, would you?

Comment: Yes, I would have, Babu. I meant $ command &> /dev/null. My apologies for typing too fast for my own good.

Answer (score 3):

For [Mac OS X v10.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard):

If you need to hide the output without letting the program know it by checking the output/error file descriptor, you can try using the following in a shell:

```
stty flusho; command ;stty -flusho
```

or if you just want to hide input from the terminal by the way:

```
stty  -echo; command ;stty  echo
```

See stty(1) manual page for more information.

For Linux, all I know is that [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx) and some Debian/Arch Linux (commented below - thanks, hendry) doesn't have the `flusho` setting (and I can't see anything other appropriate in the man-page). The `echo` setting works on the Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: My default stty under Debian/Arch does not have these options.

Comment: I should of course have mentioned that i wasn't even on the OP's OS. Edited my post.