# Hide the output of a shell command only on success?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[Hiding the output of a shell command](https://serverfault.com/questions/41964/how-to-hide-the-output-of-a-shell-application-in-linux) usually involves redirecting stderr and stdout. Is there any builtin facility or command which by default hides the output but on error dumps all the accumulated output? I would like to run this as a wrapper for remote `ssh` commands. Now I have them using redirection but I don't get a clue as to what made them fail, and they are just too verbose.

**EDIT:** In the end I created the following template based on the answer by @Belmin which I tweaked a little bit to accumulate all the previous commands from the script, use the current process identifier, automatically remove the log, and add a failure red error message when something goes wrong. In this template the initial `silent` wrappers will succeed, then fail the third command because the directory already exists:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

SILENT_LOG=/tmp/silent_log_$$.txt
trap "/bin/rm -f $SILENT_LOG" EXIT

function report_and_exit {
    cat "${SILENT_LOG}";
    echo "\033[91mError running command.\033[39m"
    exit 1;
}

function silent {
    $* 2>>"${SILENT_LOG}" >> "${SILENT_LOG}" || report_and_exit;
}

silent mkdir -v pepe
silent mkdir -v pepe2
silent mkdir -v pepe
silent mkdir -v pepe2
```

Comment: If you redirect only stdout, stderr will still show up; is this sufficient for you, or do you want to see stdout as well if there's an error?

Comment: I want to see both but only if something goes wrong, otherwise I don't want to see anything.

Comment: What I do is print stdout & stderr to a logfile so it doesn't clutter the screen. I also print stderr to the screen, so if there *is* and error I can see it. If I need details I can check the logfile, which contains the program output and the program errors in context. This way, I can 'see both but only if something goes wrong'. Does this help? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871233/write-stdout-stderr-to-a-logfile-also-write-stderr-to-screen

Comment: Is it safe to redirect stderr and stdout to the same file with two separate redirects? I thought we should always use `2>&1`, something like: `$* >>"${SILENT_LOG}" 2>&1" || report_and_exit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd setup a [bash function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) like this:

```
function suppress
{
   /bin/rm --force /tmp/suppress.out 2> /dev/null; \
   ${1+"$@"} > /tmp/suppress.out 2>&1 || \
   cat /tmp/suppress.out; \
   bin/rm /tmp/suppress.out;
}
```

Then, you could just run the command:

```
suppress foo -a bar
```

Comment: An attacker who has non-root access on your system, could try to make a symlink between rm and command call, which would point to `/etc/passswd` or some other critical file and get the contents overwritten.

Comment: BTW, order of redirects above should be: `$* > /tmp/surpress.out 2>&1` This really captures the stderr.

Comment: `$*` is not the best to handle arbitrary input. Especially when it contains spaces or flags. Most portable is `${1+"$@"}` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743454/space-in-java-command-line-arguments/743577#743577

Comment: Modified per both comments. Thanks---good info.

Comment: Spelling https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suppress

Answer (score 8):

It should be easy enough to write a script for this purpose.

Something like this completely untested script.

```
OUTPUT=`tempfile`
program_we_want_to_capture &2>1 > $OUTPUT
[ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    cat $OUTPUT
    exit 1
fi
rm $OUTPUT
```

On the other hand for commands I run as part of a script I usually want something better than simply print all the output.  I often limit what I see to the unknown.  Here is a script I adapted from something I read over a decade ago.

```
#!/bin/bash

the_command 2>&1 | awk '
BEGIN \
{
  # Initialize our error-detection flag.
  ErrorDetected = 0
}
# Following are regex that will simply skip all lines
# which are good and we never want to see
/ Added UserList source/ || \
/ Added User/ || \
/ init domainlist / || \
/ init iplist / || \
/ init urllist / || \
/ loading dbfile / || \
/^$/ {next} # Uninteresting message.  Skip it.

# Following are lines that we good and we always want to see
/ INFO: ready for requests / \
{
  print "  " $0 # Expected message we want to see.
  next
}

# any remaining lines are unexpected, and probably error messages.  These will be printed out and highlighted.
{
  print "->" $0 # Unexpected message.  Print it
  ErrorDetected=1
}

END \
{
  if (ErrorDetected == 1) {
    print "Unexpected messages (\"->\") detected in execution."
    exit 2
  }
}
'
exit $?
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't reinvent the wheel on this one. It's a common problem, notably with cron jobs, which is why `cronic`/`chronic` were created. You can likely install one from your package manager, and the usage is as simple as this:

```bash
cronic noisy_command --param paramval
```

It will suppress all output unless the noisy command produces non-trace error output or has a non-zero exit status.

Comment: I don't see it on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @MattAlexander It's there for me. Have you enabled the `universe` source for `apt`?

Comment: You are correct, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a clean way of doing this, the only thing I can think of is

- Capture the output of the command.
- Check the return value of the command and if it failed

  - display the captured output.

Implementing this might though be a interesting project but perhaps beyond Q&A.

Comment: Should be doable with a function. Hm, let me give it a try.

Comment: `cronic` does exactly this and existed at least 7 years before your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try so:

```
out=`command args...` || echo $out
```

Comment: I'd write it as `out="$(command args...)" || echo "$out"`

Comment: This only deals with STDOUT, not STDERR, where most error messages, and many info/warning messages are printed. A simple demonstration of this is define a shell function that prints to STDERR `function foobar { >&2 echo "$@" }` then use it in your one-liner `out="$(foobar x y z)" || echo "$out"`. You can see that the exit code (`$?`) is true, but it still produces output.

Comment: Using it in a script to check if the k8s-cluster is accessible: `versioncheck=$(kubectl version 2>&1 ) || { echo "Something is wrong with your kubectl configuration. Are you logged in?"; echo "$versioncheck"; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

going short with something like `tehcommand &>/tmp/$$ || cat /tmp/$$`

depends how much usability/typing you want/need. (e.g. using it as a pipe or passing the command by argument)

@zoredache short script is basically a proto-wrapper for this, which would give more robustness, handle concurrency, etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Belmin Fernandez' answer, I wrote a version that uses an secure, non-world-readable file location (so multiple instances of this script can run at the same time without race condition). It also logs the exit code.

```bash
function suppress
{
   TMP=$(mktemp)
   ${1+"$@"} > "$TMP" 2>&1 || ( echo "$* exited with $?" && cat "$TMP" )
   rm "$TMP"
}
```